# How do I access my existing cookies using Chrome?

Tags: java, cookies, selenium, gmail

I have cookies with Gmail login info, so that chrome automatically opens my Gmail.

I tried the following code, but it didn't work:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe"); 
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default"));
//I also tried using: capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--user-data-dir = C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default"));

            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

            driver.get("https://gmail.com");
```

I checked the directory of `C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default` it is okay.
What is the problem in here?

Comment: Just wanted to know that you wanted to open gmail or you wanted to open something else but gmail is opening instead of that. Please clarify.

Comment: I wanted to open my `gmail` without entering password and login using coockies

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [Known issues](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#Known_Issues) section on the Chrome Driver official wiki page I haven't noticed before:

> **Known Issues**
>
> 3 . Cannot specify a custom profile

Now, I don't know whether this is or isn't outdated. I could not find a bug report for this. It's true that you can't specify a custom profile via `Capabilities` (as of July 2013), as you discovered. But there is a solution...

---

## The Solution

Here's how I managed to make it run:

```
ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
opt.setBinary("E:\\some\\path\\chrome.exe");
opt.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
```

Notice the path to the User data directory - it *does not* have the `\\Default` part. And in that case, it works just fine for me, opens up the Chrome profile stored with all the cookies and logins.

I have no idea why the `Capabilities` solution does not work. It might be worthwile to [file a bug](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list) as I could not find one on topic.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I tried using all combination. I did include `--user-data-dir as well...It did not work

Comment: @Buras Edited twice, finally got a solution.

Comment: Do I have to import `setBinary` method. I got a message in Eclipse: "method setBinary in ChromeOptions is not applicable for the argument String"?

Comment: @Buras Well, if your chrome is on your Path, you don't have to set this one at all. Otherwise, you are right. [The JavaDocs only show `ChromeOptions#setBinary(File file)`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html#setBinary%28java.io.File%29). My Selenium 2.33.0 takes a String, too, seems like an undocumented change. Either upgrade your Selenium or simply change the String path to a `File` instance.