# Chrome arguments doesn't work

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

anybody know why chrome arguments does't work?

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class testowa  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capability.setCapability("chrome.args",
                Arrays.asList("--disable-web-security", "--start-maximized"));
        WebDriver driver = null;
        try {
            URL hub_url = new URL("http://192.168.56.101:4444/wd/hub");
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(hub_url, capability);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.get("file:///home/test/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

I've tried also without "--" before switchers and giving only one argument... Chrome starts, but without activated flags.

I use newest chromedriver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [recently discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668923/how-to-acess-my-existing-cookies-using-chrome/17682825#17682825) that the `Capabilities` class does not work properly with current Selenium and Chrome for some reason (as of Selenium 2.33.0, Chrome 30 and July 2013).

The answer I linked is also, I believe, the solution to your problem. Simply use `ChromeOptions`, these have been working for me well:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArgument("--disable-web-security");
options.addArgument("--start-maximized");

// For use with RemoteWebDriver:
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: Link that you provided is to documentation of older chrome driver and it a fragment of selenium docs.

Comment: @maclor Edited with a different answer. Hopefully at least this usage of Capabilities will work, I can't test it right now.

Comment: Well, this is annoying but it works! I had to include the `selenium-chrome-driver` JAR (instead of just remote-driver) in my project to get `ChromeOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

Those who are looking for .Net C# and Selenium, to load insecure script

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something this, Change the path and slashing accoding to your specifications :-

```
            WebDriver driver=null;
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./src//lib//chromedriver");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("test-type");
            options.addArgument("--start-maximized");
            options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
            options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
            capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","./src//lib//chromedriver");
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
            driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
            driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Below is the link where all available chrome flags are listed :-

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/